# No consigo instalar ODBC Driver for SQL Server para Centos7

Tags: odbc, centos7, microsoft

tengo un problema con los drivers de microsoft de ODBC para centos7, ya que he probado a descargarlos he instalarlos de varios repositorios de linux y nada, falla la instalación o no los encuentra. Tambien he buscado en la página oficial que tiene microsoft para bajarlos y magicamente para centos no tienen. Estoy un poco perdido en este tema y me esta volviendo loco, ya que toda la plataforma que tengo creada funciona a traves de una base de datos sql server y no consigo hacerla funcionar por esto. ¿Sabéis de algun sitio donde encontrarlo? o ¿alguna idea de como instalar esto correctamente?.

El servidor corre con php 7.1 aúnque se puede subir y bajar dicha versión.

Comment: Si entiendo usted tiene un servidor Centos7 donde tiene una aplicación en PHP la cual debe conectar a una base de datos microsoft, ¿y que servidor de aplicaciones tiene?, por que hasta lo que yo tengo entendido el Driver ODBC lo deberia configurar en el servidor de aplicaciones?

Comment: En teoría estaba configurado en el servidor de aplicaciones. Pero ni aún así asi que al final he optado por cambiar a un servidor windows y solucionar dichos problemas. Gracias por la ayuda.